# Sub-Navigator for not working

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native

I am trying to create a sub-navigation functionality in my app and want to display a list of my so called cardviews (right now ive just stored them in a ScrollView, but nevermind that), and my goal is to display the cards in such a manner so that the content in component one shows when I press one and two when I press two.

```
/* @flow */
'use strict';

import React, {
  Component,
    Navigator,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Image,
} from 'react-native';

import styles from '../Styles/style';
import home from '../Styles/home';
import feed from '../Styles/feed';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

var CardView = require('./CardView');
var colors = require('../Styles/colorscheme');

var Home = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      componentSelected: 'One'
    }
  },

  changeComponent: function(component) {
    this.setState({
      componentSelected: component  
    })
  },

  renderComponent: function(component) {
      if(component == 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={styles.controller}>
          <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.controlItem} 
              onPress={() => 
                this.props.changeComponent('One') }>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>Friends</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.controlItem}
              onPress={() => 
                this.props.changeComponent('Two') }>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>Local</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}

      </View>
    )
  }
})

var ComponentTwo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <CardView
                    name="Short Name"
                    fullname="Full Name"
                    distance="Component Two"
                    title="Example Title" 
                    message="Lorem Ipsum dolor set blablabla" 
                    score="[Symbol for progress]"
                    stars="smallthree"
                    starcolors={colors.General.black}
                    vouched="Example Vouch" />
                </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>   
    )
  }
})


var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <CardView
                    name="Short Name"
                    fullname="Full Name"
                    distance="Component Two"
                    title="Example Title" 
                    message="Lorem Ipsum dolor set blablabla" 
                    score="[Symbol for progress]"
                    stars="smallthree"
                    starcolors={colors.General.black}
                    vouched="Example Vouch" />
                </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      )
  }
})
```

The error that is being returned is unexpected token at line 75, which is at the render function of the first component in the code (i.e. at "var ComponentTwo"). And I have no idea why, I have looked for missing commas or semicolons for a while, but I am lost.

Comment: the first view tag in your home class render method is never closed, try and remove it >

    render: function() {
        return (
          <View>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
          ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question was both to remove the excess View tag as the comment to the original question stated, and the fact that the onPress property was not passed via props so it was written as 
`onPress={() => this.changeComponent('One') }`.

But I had also forgotten to add a module.exports.

Thank you!